# WCF Subscriber to Azure SB with multiple operations

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azureservicebus

I am trying to make a WCF Service that both publishes messages to a topic and also subscribes to that topic. The idea is to have my service expose endpoints for managing a customer (i.e. CreateCustomer, EditCustomer, DeleteCustomer, etc). Then I want it to publish a message to a topic after it completes each operation (i.e. OnCustomerCreated, OnCustomerChanged, OnCustomerDeleted, etc.)

For Example, A client application will hit the EditCustomer message on my service. I will immediately publish an OnCustomerChanged message with the customer object provided. My service (the same one the customer hit) will have another contract that takes an OnCustomerChanged and updates my database.

My question is, do I have to make a separate Subscription on my topic for each message type (i.e. OnCustomerChangedSubscription, OnCustomerDeletedSubscription, etc.) so that I can properly route messages of different types to the correct endpoint?

If that is case, I would need a bunch of single-method contracts so that I could configure the wcf endpoints properly:

i.e:

```
 <service name="site.Services.Business.Managers.CustomerManager">
   <!-- endpoint that clients will hit -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="site.Services.Business.Contracts.ICustomerManager" />
   <!-- endpoint that publishes messages-->
    <endpoint address="sb://test-site.servicebus.windows.net/Managers/CustomerManager" 
              binding="netTcpRelayBinding" 
              contract="site.Services.Business.Contracts.ICustomerManager" 
              behaviorConfiguration="sbTokenProvider" />
    <!-- One Endpoint for each message type (this will get very cumbersome and the contract will only have 1 method on it) -->
    <endpoint address="sb://test-site.servicebus.windows.net/Managers/CustomerManager"
                  binding="netMessagingBinding"
                  listenUri="sb://test-site.servicebus.windows.net/Managers/CustomerManager/subscriptions/OnCustomerDeleted"
                  behaviorConfiguration ="sbTokenProvider"
                  contract="site.Services.Business.Contracts.CustomerManager.IOnCustomerDeleted" />
    <endpoint address="sb://test-site.servicebus.windows.net/Managers/CustomerManager"
                  binding="netMessagingBinding"
                  listenUri="sb://test-site.servicebus.windows.net/Managers/CustomerManager/subscriptions/OnCustomerCreated"
                  behaviorConfiguration ="sbTokenProvider"
                  contract="site.Services.Business.Contracts.CustomerManager.IOnCustomerCreated" />
…etc

  </service>
```

An alternative would be to create a single Subscriber (Allmessages), only having one contract with a `HandleMessage(BrokeredMessage message)` operation, and then determine inside that method with method to call on my service. That doesn't seem like I am doing the right thing there though either. I am essentially taking in all messages and determining the handler inside the service.

What I am looking for is a way to have a a service that implements 3 contracts, ICustomerPublisher (already have this), ICustomerManager (exposed over http to clients), and ICustomerSubscriber.

ICustomerSubscriber would look like:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICustomerSubscriber
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnCustomerCreated(ICustomerMessage message);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnCustomerDeleted(ICustomerMessage message);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnCustomerChanged(ICustomerMessage message);
}
```

and I would be able to call:

```
publisher.Publish<OnCustomerChanged>(new CustomerChangedMessage(customer));
```

and have my OnCustomerChanged method receive that message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Service Bus Topics don't require WCF (unlike Relays), so I don't see why you would need WCF contracts for publishing and subscribing to the Topic. Why not use the plain ServiceBus SDK?

You seem to say that you want a single service to receive messages from clients, put them on the Topic, remove them from the Topic, and update the database -- in other words, send messages to itself. Do you really intend to make the subscriber and publisher different services?

Comment: The reason I want to have it subscribe to itself is because I have other services that need to know when these events happen as well (One example is a Notification service that may send out an email to customer, or account holder after creation). I know I could implement a method on my service for checking the the subscription for messages, but then I would have to create a scheduler that would execute that method regularly. It would be better if my service was "pushed" the message via reading it from a queue so I don't have to schedule a check for messages.

Answer (score 1):

First: Yes, if the service has per-request activation, then your SubscriptionClient won't get a chance to run except while the service responds to an external request, and it will have to be created and torn down every time. The only feasible way to keep the SubscriptionClient running would be to change activation to singleton.

But I think the better approach is to pull the SubscriptionClient out of this service entirely and have it run on its own. If you want it to run on-prem, then it could be in a Windows Service or console app; in the cloud, it could be a WebJob or Worker Role. Again, I don't see why your OnMessage method needs to be a WCF Operation.

Second: If there's only one Subscription, then each message can be received and completed by only one client. If multiple clients need to get a copy of each message, then each client needs its own subscription. The subscriptions can share the same filter conditions, or no conditions.

Comment: The reason I want to use the same wcf service is to limit costs. I have several other services running already, and adding another service to perform 1 operation (HandleMessage) would not be very cost effective, especially if it is run as a worker role that is essentially in an infinite loop. My thought was, if I use a netMessageBinding endpoint, an instance of the service is only created when messages are added to the queue, so I wouldn't be paying for compute on an infinite loop when most of the time there would be nothing to process.

Comment: So were you trying to set things up like this blog post, and it didn't work? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2011/10/07/using-service-bus-queues-with-wcf.aspx

Comment: yea, I was getting a Fault every time it tried to retrieve messages from the queue, but since it was all happening within the netMessagingBinding, I couldn't catch it anywhere and see what the fault was.

Comment: In that case, on your first issue, I really can't say if you'll have issues or not since I've never seen netMessageBinding used that way. My own recommendation would be to move the Subscription client functionality into a WebJob without WCF and either run either continuously or triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a suitable way to accomplish what I mentioned above. Instead, I did the following:

Created a default subscription to my customer topic with no filter.

In the constructor for my WCF service, I use the SubscriptionClient to register as a subscriber:

```
    public CustomerManager()
    {
        //set up automapper and IoC
        Initializer.Initialize();
        Publisher = IoCContainer.GetContainer().Resolve<IPublisher>("CustomerManager");
        Publisher.Subscribe("AllMessages");

        var client =
            SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"), "customertopic", "AllMessages", ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

        client.OnMessage(m =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message Received.");
            HandleMessage(m);
        });
    }
```

My HandleMessage method takes a BrokeredMessage as a parameter and then determines what internal operation to call based on the message body type.

```
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
    public void HandleMessage(BrokeredMessage message)
    {

        var customerMessage = message.GetBody<CustomerMessage>();

        switch (customerMessage.EventName)
        {
            case "OnCreated" : 
                OnCustomerCreated(customerMessage);
                break;
            case "OnDeleted" : 
                OnCustomerDeleted(customerMessage as OnDeleted);
                break;
            case "OnChanged" :
                OnCustomerChanged(customerMessage as OnChanged);
                break;
        }

        message.Complete(); //mark the message as completed

    }
```

I have a couple of concerns though.

First, I use instance per request configuration for my service. Will this cause any kind of message consistency issues? Such as, when I have multiple instances of CustomerManager, will each one try and handle the same message, or will the SubscriptionClient ensure that only 1 CustomerManager will get the message?

Second, I want to be able to subscribe other services to my AllMessages subscription. One example is a notification service. I may want to be able to send a push notification to the account owner when a new customer is created (OnCustomerCreated), or I might want to ask the customer to verify the information that changed on their account (OnCustomerChanged). Can I still subscribe other services to the CustomerTopic AllMessages, or will marking the message complete (as I do at the end of my HandleMessage method) clear out the message for other subscribers also? More technically, will adding another subscriber to the AllMessages subscription result in multicasting or balancing?